# Floating point operations is slower when small values are used?

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following simple program that multiplies two different floating point numbers many times. As you can see, one of the numbers is very small. When I calculate the time of executing both multiplications, I was surprised that the little number takes much longer than the other one. It seems that working with small doubles is slower... Does anyone know what is happening?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    long iterations = 10000000;
    double result;
    double number = 0.1D;
    double numberA = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double numberB = 0.0008D;

    long startTime, endTime,elapsedTime;


    //Multiply numberA
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++)
        result = number * numberA;

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Number A) Time elapsed: " + elapsedTime + " ms");

    //Multiply numberB
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++)
        result = number * numberB;

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Number B) Time elapsed: " + elapsedTime + " ms");
}
```

Result:

```
Number A) Time elapsed: 3546 ms
Number B) Time elapsed: 110 ms
```

Platform Windows, Java 1.6.0_07

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 3):

When operating near the minimum representation of an IEEE 758 floating-point value, you are likely to get results that are "[denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal)".  These are sometimes, though not always, processed more slowly.  I suspect that the JVM is handling them specially somehow rather than relying on pure hardware support, leading to some performance degradation.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the compiler replaced

```
number * numberB;
```

with its exact value, because `number` and `numberB` are both constant values that the compiler knows have not changed by that point. However, `numberA` is not a constant value (its value is platform-specific), and so you have to actually do the calculation every time. Try replacing `Double.MIN_VALUE` with its actual value, and see if they perform similarly.

Comment: Nop, I replaced it with 4.9E-324 and it get the same results... Thanks!!

Comment: Do it with 0.0000008 and start to increase the zeros before the 8.

Comment: Hmm, I also entirely missed the fact that you're multiplying epsilon by a number less than 1.. That almost certainly has something to do with it!

Comment: I mean draw a histogram based on logarithmic scaled test values.

Comment: I ran it in Ubuntu 8.04 and get:

Number A) Time elapse : 44 ms
Number B) Time elapse : 49 ms

There is something strange with Windows JVM...

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you enter the range of "denormal" numbers (see IEEE754 format).  Handling these numbers may require more time in the floating point unit.

Comment: I ran it in Ubuntu 8.04 and get: 
Number A) Time elapse : 44 ms 
Number B) Time elapse : 49 ms 
There is something strange with Windows JVM...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error in Windows JVM